# illegal text reloc to non_lazy_ptr error while building in xcode 4 with libav* libraries

Tags: xcode4, ffmpeg, linker-errors, libav, non-lazy-ptr

I'm trying to build a simple application that uses ffmpeg's libav* libraries in xcode 4 and getting the following error:

ld: illegal text reloc to non_lazy_ptr from /ffmpeg/temp/ffmpeg-0.8/builduni/lib/libavcodec.a(ac3.o) in _ff_ac3_bit_alloc_calc_psd for architecture i386

I've already tried to run ranlib -c libavcodec.a to fix this problem, but nothing happend.
One more thing: my libav* libraries are fat binaries (i386 + x86_64).

Any ideas what can it be?

Comment: i've found similar problem here http://hi-im-shigerello.blogspot.com/2011/04/transition-mayhem-xcode-4.html
But adding fvisibility=hidden didn' help too :(

Answer (score 4):

I have the same error. Finally, I got the solution at 
http://lists.apple.com/archives/unix-porting/2008/Jan/msg00027.html

just add other link flag:

```
-read_only_relocs suppress
```

> *** EXPLANATION *** The two assembly commands load the absolutes address of _trail into R15. Doing so is fine if _trail is ultimately
>   in the same linkage unit. _trail is in libmodule.dylib. For this to
>   work, at runtime the dynamic loader (dyld) would have to rewrite the
>   two instructions. Normally dyld only updates data pointers. One work
>   around is to make libdyalog an archive (e.g. libdyalog.a) and link
>   that with pere.s. Then all the code would be in the same linkage unit,
>   so there would be no need for runtime text relocs. The runtime (dyld)
>   does support text relocs (updating instructions) for i386, but you
>   need to link with -read_only_relocs suppress.