# Illegal text-relocation error, how to embed a text file?

Tags: ios, ipad, parsing

I am currently developing an application in which the first step its to load a text file and read its contents.

For example:

```
string file = "myfile.txt";
```

i am calling another function in which i want to look for a certain pattern/occurrence

```
void read(string pattern, const char *content) {

   char subString [blocksize];
   int n;

   char *search = pattern;
   pos = strstr(content,search);

   .....
```

The function works perfectly on my Mac, but once I try to compile the application the compiler throws some error `ld : illegal text-relocation.`

The text file is in the same folder as the target app.
I'm assuming this has something to do with embedding the text file?

hope someone can help or give a hint !
thanks in advance

Comment: check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650178/illegal-text-reloc-to-non-lazy-ptr-error-while-building-in-xcode-4-with-libav-l